# How to convert an array of objects as string in symfony 3?

Tags: php, arrays, object, orm, symfony-3.1

I'm getting the following error while implementing the many-to-many relationship in b/w 2 entities(Product & Offer):

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class FoodBundle\Entity\Product could
>   not be converted to string

Where Product entity is in relation with the Offer entity.
My aim here was to avail offers to products in many-to-many relationship.

This piece of code is creating it as I guess from the error.

```
class Offer
{
    public function addProduct(\FoodBundle\Entity\Product $product)
    {
        $this->product[] = $product;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: You need to define __toString() (http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

Comment: How do you want your entity to be displayed as string?

Comment: Thanks to @Taha Paksu & others for question editing help. It's solved by the following answer.

Comment: Thanks @lanis for the useful link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is common when you've created the CRUD automatically.

The problem is that you need to select from a `<select>` a **Product in the Offer form** and symfony cannot draw the select because **the Product class doesn't specify which field should be rendered**.

Go to your Product Entity and add the magic `__toString` method  (provide it if you can) and it should look like :

```
class Product {

    public function __toString(){
        // Or change the property that you want to show in the select.
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```